# SSH Windows 10, figure out what version of

Tags: ssh, windows-10

How do I determine the version of SSH installed on my Windows 10 Desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are asking about the version distributed with Windows (if not, then you may have multiple versions and the answer will vary depending on which version you are talking about).

In Explorer, go to `c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH` and right click on `ssh`. Select *Properties* from the context menu. Click on the *Details* tab. The version information will be displayed.